# C# Error trying to edit item of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So when i try to edit or add or delete from a DataGrid in WPF is giving me 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

```
providersDataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true;
providersDataGrid.CanUserDeleteRows = true;
providersTableAdapter adapter = new providersTableAdapter();
adapter.Fill(ds.providers);
providersDataGrid.ItemsSource = adapter.GetData().Rows;
```

i have activated Autogenerate Columns.

So how i can do it? thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you checked if IsReadOnly is true?

Comment: yes is was false so it was the DataView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `ItemsSource` property to the actual `DataView`:

```
providersDataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.providers.DefaultView;
```

or

```
providersDataGrid.ItemsSource = adapter.GetData();
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is very good, but... i can update the value using  Providersadapter.Update(ds.providers);

Comment: How does this relate to your original question? Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow